# Variance for grouped bivariate data.

Tags: random-variables, conditional-probability, variance, bivariate-distributions

If for example I have two random variables X and Y. X stands for height and Y for weight. I compute the conditional variance for Y at each X. ( Both are discrete). Then can I compute the total variance by summing each weighted conditional variance where weights would be number of cases the measurements have been taken and then dividing the total amount of measurements taken?

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance). Your calculation would only be the first term.

Comment: Ok, but it seems as if this is formula for total variance not conditional variance? Would this give a different result than just regular Var(y)?

Comment: start with the weighted average of the conditional variances and add the vriance of the conditional means to find the total unconditional variance.